# How to count cells between two cells that contains a pattern in Excel?

Tags: excel, search, cell

I have for example theses lines :
[image: excel]

I'm looking for a formula that count my column D for example.
But I want a formula that count these cells between a cell that contains the pattern "Scénario 3" and a cell that contains the dark blue color.

Is that possible ? I've seen the COUNTIF formula but nothing about a pattern to recognize cells and a range...

Example :
I want to count cells inside this range ]"Cell that contains 'Scénario 3'", "Dark blue colored cell"[.
In the picture uploaded, the output will be 2.

Example 2 :
[image]
Let's take another example maybe more simple : I want to count lines between A1 and A5 (both excluded). So the output will be 3. But I'm looking for a formula that count lines, and can find me automatically the range between a text ("Scénario 1" here) and the next occurence of cell highlighted in dark blue.

Comment: I am not following your question.  Could you please provide an example of what you are looking for.  Pictures say a thousand words.

Comment: Yes sure, sorry for my english. I added an example on the original post

Comment: Are you saying if the cell is highlighted dark blue then count it?

Comment: Oops, I've done a mistake, no it shouldn't been counted, neither the highlited cell nor cell that contains 'Scénario 3'

Comment: I added another example, I hope it is more clear with picture :)

Comment: Thank you for updating your post.  That makes sense now

Comment: Are you wanting this to be running?  Meaning below the blue row in your example 2 there is another scenario with blank number of lines then a blue highlighted row?

Comment: Yes exactly. There will be multiple scenarios below, with the same "pattern" (blue row, ...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196913/discussion-between-jojoe-and-zman3).

Comment: @Jojoe ... reading up becasue an user wanted to post an answer... what is yuour solution? Post it as answer to get it out the questions-unsolved section.

Comment: @internet .. I see your comment posted as answer is removed. You now can reply your answer as comment here due to my pm here at the question.